# Css text/image wrap not working

Tags: html, css, magento

Why does the text wrap not work around these images? I work in magento text editor, that why i do not use a css style sheet but write it into the code.

**Not working version:
https://jsfiddle.net/mastervision/s8grhjab/**

i used TextWrap [image]

**I worked for me in many other situations like here:
https://jsfiddle.net/mastervision/s6o64m06/**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <style> 
        .newspaper {
            /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
            -webkit-column-count: 2;
            -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
            -webkit-column-rule-style: outset;
            -webkit-column-rule-width: 1px;



            /* Firefox */
            -moz-column-count: 2;
            -moz-column-gap: 40px;
            -moz-column-rule-style: outset;
            -moz-column-rule-width: 1px;

            column-count: 2;
            column-gap: 40px;
            column-rule-style: outset;
            column-rule-width: 1px;
        }

        .TextWrap {
        float: right;
        margin:10px;}

        @media only screen and (max-width: 40em) {
            .newspaper{
                /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ 
                -webkit-column-count :  1 ; 
                -webkit-column-gap :  0px ; 
                -webkit-column-rule-style : outset ; 
                -webkit-column-rule-width :  1px ;

                /* Firefox */ 
                -moz-column-count :  1 ; 
                -moz-column-gap :  0px ; 
                -moz-column-rule-style : outset ; 
                -moz-column-rule-width :  1px ;

                column-count :  1 ; 
                column-gap :  0px ; 
                column-rule-style : outset ; 
                column-rule-width :  1px ; 
            } 

        .TextWrap {
        float: right;
        margin:10px;}



        </style>
        </head>
        <body>


        <div class="newspaper">
        <p><span style="font-size: x-large;">Gentleman Basis-Ausstattung</span><br />

    ="font-size: medium;">LINK ADVANCED TIPPS.</span></span></p>

        </body>
        </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's failing because you are **not** using the class `.TextWrap` anywhere in the code. Add that class to the paragraph that contain the images and it will be done:

```
<p class="TextWrap">
    <img title="Schwarzer cap-toe Oxford" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/OHNE.TEXT_Landingpage_1200pix_08.jpg"}}" alt="Schwarzer cap-toe Oxford" width="300" height="155" />
</p>
```

You can see it on any of the links below:

- https://jsfiddle.net/s6o64m06/2/
- https://jsfiddle.net/s8grhjab/2/

(Notice that the images would need to be on their own paragraph for this to work, that's why I changed the code a little around the first picture)

Comment: Thank you for a solid answer. May the force be with you. :)